# High response times with Ajax True Client script

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

We are facing an issue with Ajax True Client script. When recording and replaying the script. One transaction took more than 60 sec time to load the page. Same behaviour observed after executing scenario in controller as well. But, if we manually perform the same transaction, it took only 8 sec. There is huge gap between the expected response times. Can any one suggest the fix?

Comment: How are we supposed to help without any [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), no implementation description?

Comment: It's difficult to analyze without further details.
Try checking your steps (and transaction) end-events. If there is a specific element that indicates the transaction's end, It's advisable to wait for that object.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of external resource download attempts by the script, which are not visible to you when you manually browse the page.

For example, if the page requests data from Google Analytics, or Facebook, and cannot access these sites (due to company restrictions, firewall, etc.), the response time would jump up to 60 seconds (timeout), but when you browse manually, you will not experience the timeout, since the browser behaves differently.

To resolve this issue, you should first find out which site is the script attempting to download data from? You can do this using a browser's developer tools (such as F12 tool in Google Chrome), and looking at the "**Network**" tab. Once you use this tab and browse to the web page, you should see the external HTTP requests. Make a list of these sites.

Once you know which external sites the page goes to, you can then use the `Utils.removeAutoFilter` JS command in your TruClient script:

From the Truclient Toolbox, choose "**Misc**" > "**Evaluate Javascript Code**" and add it to the **first line** of your script.

Then you can set the JS code in this action to:

```
Utils.removeAutoFilter(url, isIncluded);
```

for example, to prevent the script from downloading data from facebook:

```
Utils.removeAutoFilter('http://facebook.com', true);
Utils.removeAutoFilter('https://facebook.com', true);
Utils.removeAutoFilter('http://www.facebook.com', true);
Utils.removeAutoFilter('https://www.facebook.com', true);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information..:) I will try this way.